# Email an individual added after a list of people is created in sharepoint designer workflows

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, notifications

I have a list for an event. I add names when I first create a new item but sometimes the inputee forgets to add a name. He wants to add them later, and when they get added ONLY they get a notification email (not the whole group)

I have researched this for weeks and below is as close as I got. Please, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Workflow so far]

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of the SharePoint Event Item? And describing about what can happened and what is wanted?